# Direct to another xaml user control page when button clicked C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

How do I direct to another `xaml` user control page from my main window when i click the button from my main window.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        \\what am i suppose to write here;
    }
```

Thanks any help appreciated

my code on my catergory xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="KinectButton.view.Catergory"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="373" d:DesignWidth="480" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded" Name="grid1">
    <StackPanel Name="myStackPanel" Margin="1,0,120,54">
        <Image Height="319" Name="myImg" Stretch="Fill" Width="357" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,0,121,54"></Grid>


    <Label Content="Label" Name="message" Margin="2,317,121,0" />
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="" Margin="357,77,0,222" Click="Button1_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\103159T\Desktop\KinectButton1\KinectButton\Images\AERO.png"></ImageBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    <Button x:Name="Button3" Content="" Margin="357,147,0,148" Click="Button3_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\103159T\Desktop\KinectButton1\KinectButton\Images\MIT.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="" Margin="357,224,0,0" Height="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button4_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\103159T\Desktop\KinectButton1\KinectButton\Images\MECHATRONIC.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="Button5" Content="" Margin="357,298,0,0" Click="Button5_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\103159T\Desktop\KinectButton1\KinectButton\Images\TMT.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="" Margin="357,0,0,294" Click="Button2_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\103159T\Desktop\KinectButton1\KinectButton\Images\ECC.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

i have a few buttons and some image on it..

Comment: Do you want to open a new windows or do you want to load the page? How are you currently showing pages?

Comment: i want to load the page. currently im using kinect to run my application, and why i hover my hand over the start button, i want a new page to come out.. any ideas?

Comment: You need to be more specific: what do you mean by 'a new page to come out'? Is it a page or a window? Does `ShowDialog` or `Show` what you are looking for?

Comment: Its a window, my mainwindow is the parent and i have another window called "catergory" which is the child

Comment: could you post the code of your xaml window "catergory"

Comment: nvm it was my mistake, catergory was a usercontrol not a window. my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to open a window is pretty easy

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // based on your comments your window is called catergory
        var catergory = new Catergory();
        catergory.Show();
    }
```

Comment: tried it, the error "The name 'Catergory' does not exist in the current context". my window is called Catergory.xaml

Comment: of course, you need an instance of your xaml window. see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help! but now i encountered another error <The type or namespace name 'Catergory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) >

Comment: could you open a new question for this issue? don't forget to show us your source code ;) btw: no offense, but you should consider to get a good c# book. It's easier to start and it will save you a lot of time in the end.

Comment: @Joel, My view file is not a window but  `User Control(WPF)` view, how would I able to call it. as `.Show` is meant for Window.

Comment: You cannot open a User control like a window. You need to wrap it into a window.